# how FULL JOIN works?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

**Customer table:**

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|  2 | Khilan   |  25 | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  4 | Chaitali |  25 | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  27 | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Komal    |  22 | MP        |  4500.00 |
|  7 | Muffy    |  24 | Indore    | 10000.00 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

**Orders table:**

```
+-----+---------------------+-------------+--------+
|OID  | DATE                | CUSTOMER_ID | AMOUNT |
+-----+---------------------+-------------+--------+
| 102 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00 |           3 |   3000 |
| 100 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00 |           3 |   1500 |
| 101 | 2009-11-20 00:00:00 |           2 |   1560 |
| 103 | 2008-05-20 00:00:00 |           4 |   2060 |
+-----+---------------------+-------------+--------+
```

**Query:**

```
   SELECT  ID, NAME, AMOUNT, DATE
   FROM CUSTOMERS
   FULL OUTER JOIN ORDERS
   ON CUSTOMERS.ID = ORDERS.CUSTOMER_ID;
```

According to [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-full-joins.htm), the output should be this:

```
+------+----------+--------+---------------------+
| ID   | NAME     | AMOUNT | DATE                |
+------+----------+--------+---------------------+
|    1 | Ramesh   |   NULL | NULL                |
|    2 | Khilan   |   1560 | 2009-11-20 00:00:00 |
|    3 | kaushik  |   3000 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00 |
|    3 | kaushik  |   1500 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00 |
|    4 | Chaitali |   2060 | 2008-05-20 00:00:00 |
|    5 | Hardik   |   NULL | NULL                |
|    6 | Komal    |   NULL | NULL                |
|    7 | Muffy    |   NULL | NULL                |
|    3 | kaushik  |   3000 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00 |
|    3 | kaushik  |   1500 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00 |
|    2 | Khilan   |   1560 | 2009-11-20 00:00:00 |
|    4 | Chaitali |   2060 | 2008-05-20 00:00:00 |
+------+----------+--------+---------------------+
```

This is my real output instead:

```
╔════╦══════════╦════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║   NAME   ║ AMOUNT ║          DATE           ║
╠════╬══════════╬════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ Ramesh   ║ NULL   ║ NULL                    ║
║  2 ║ Khilan   ║ 1560   ║ 2009-11-20 00:00:00.000 ║
║  3 ║ kaushik  ║ 1500   ║ 2009-10-08 00:00:00.000 ║
║  3 ║ kaushik  ║ 3000   ║ 2009-10-08 00:00:00.000 ║
║  4 ║ Chaitali ║ 2060   ║ 2008-05-20 00:00:00.000 ║
║  5 ║ Hardik   ║ NULL   ║ NULL                    ║
║  6 ║ Komal    ║ NULL   ║ NULL                    ║
║  7 ║ Muffy    ║ NULL   ║ NULL                    ║
╚════╩══════════╩════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

So, I want to understand how the Full join exactly works as I'm not getting the same results as Tutorilaspoint site. I also want to know why the Full join query I posted above will have the exact **same results** as a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: You would need to put in orders for customer ID not existing in the customer​ table to see any difference. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join/27458534#27458534

Comment: I think you are misreading/misinterpreting the TutorialsPoint link.  Your output is what I would expect.

Comment: The tutorialpoints example seems to be wrong. It makes no sense why it would duplicate some of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your results are correct.  Think of a `FULL OUTER JOIN` like this:

- It returns all rows from an `INNER JOIN` on the two tables.
- It returns all rows from the first table with no matches in the second.
- It returns all rows from the second table with no matches in the first.

In your data example, all rows in the second table have matches in the first (that is, `Customer_Id` always matches a valid customer).  Only the first two bullet points describe the result set.

I have no idea where their result set is coming from.  My best guess is that it comes from the MySQL code.  That code is not correct and does not approximate a `FULL OUTER JOIN` in any way.

Besides the obvious recommendation of finding a better tutorial, this is also a really bad example.  In a properly created database, `FULL OUTER JOIN` is almost never necessary.  The keys in one table should match the keys in the reference table.  That is, you should *never* have a non-NULL `Customer_Id` that is not valid in the `Customers` table.

Comment: Strange. Why no grace period on that edit?  Was there a comment deleted?

Comment: Helpful comment that `FULL OUTER JOIN` is seldom needed; perhaps this was one reason why MySQL and few other databases do not natively support it.  @Martin yes

Comment: @MartinSmith Is it correct to say that a `FULL OUTER JOIN` is a `UNION` of `RIGHT JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: And why exactly I'm getting the same results as if I'm doing a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: @Dablackninja - Because you don't have any value in `ORDERS.CUSTOMER_ID`, which not exists in `CUSTOMERS.ID` column.